# Updating a value in a random row through java in a sql table

Tags: java, sql

[Image of my table as it is when I start this program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRIJK.png)

What I have is a mostly empty table and I am trying to assign a value to a fixed number of elements. The column I am trying to edit is "Geschlecht" and the number of rows I want to edit is "copyMaen" (~50.000 entries). I would like to only select the rows where the value of "Geschlecht" was NULL before and I would like to select the rows randomly.

I am using SQLite through a JDBC driver.

This is the first time for me working with sql. This is how I tried to do it.

```
                try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Geschlecht FROM individuen WHERE Geschlecht IS NULL;");
        PreparedStatement ps = DBController.connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE individuen");
        while (copyMaen != 0) {
            if (rs.getRowId((int) (Math.random() * ReadCSV.sumBev)) == null) {
                ps.setInt(2, 0);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                copyMaen--;
            }
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Obviosly this throws me Errors and I am not really sure how to go on from there. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: you want , like, while Geschlecht is null then update by Random values right ?

Comment: I want to set "Geschlecht" to 0 in a number of rows (int copyMean) but without changing any other values in the table. And it should only be updated if it was null before, of course. English is not my native language and I'm not even good at describing programming problems in my langue. Sorry!

Comment: see my posted answer, which will help you most.

Comment: What RDMBS are you using, as the answer will vary depending on this.  For example, in SQL Server you could use RAND() to generate a randomi(ish) number.  Then you could test this to see if you want to update the NULL value or not.

Comment: I am using SQLite through a JDBC Driver.
Whould using RAND() look something like this?
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Geschlecht FROM individuen ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anybody interested this is the solution:

```
try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        String select = "SELECT ID FROM individuen WHERE Geschlecht is NULL ORDER BY RANDOM()" +
        " LIMIT " + Integer.toString(copyMaen);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(select);
        PreparedStatement ps = DBController.connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE individuen set Geschlecht  = ? WHERE ID = ?;");
        // rs.beforeFirst();
        int count = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {
            ps.setInt(1, 0);
            ps.setInt(2, rs.getInt(1));
            ps.addBatch();
            if (count%100==0) {
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            count++;
        }
        DBController.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        ps.executeBatch();
        DBController.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this would be also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

> Below update query is enough for update all row where Geschlecht  is
>   null.

```
try {
        Statement stmt = DBController.connection.createStatement();
        String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE individuen set Geschlecht  = ? where Geschlecht IS NULL";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, "0"); // set zero where Geschlecht null found
        // execute update SQL stetement
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a bunch. But this is not quite what I need. This updates all "null" values in "Geschlecht" to 0. But I would like only for a set amount to be changed.
What would be great as well, were if the rows that are being changed would be selected randomly.

Comment: Please, can you provide me a little bit more explanation ?